# Lists of lists python recursive permutation

Tags: python, recursion, permutation, nested-lists

How do you manipulate a list of list of string in a specific way so that

```
lst = [ [a, b], [c, d, e], [f, a, e] ]
# turns into
lst = [ [a, b], [b, a], [c, d, e], [c, e, d], [d, c, e],etc...]
#there are 14 combinations
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import *

combo_list = []

for i in your_list:
    for j in permutations(i, len(i)):
        combo_list.append(j)
```

Comment: thanks, can you also show me how to put the list of lists in alpha order judging from the first element in each list so it's like.. lst = [ [a,b], [a,c] ]

Comment: Just call `combo_list.sort()` and it will be sorted.